# How to start an intent without 'showing' the second application android

Tags: android, delphi, android-intent, delphi-xe5

I have an application for Android that reads data from a bar code scanning application. I have successfully created an intent to

1. Open that barcode application
2. Scan product from that application
3. return to my application, pulling the value from barcode application.
4. manipulate the data I've retrieved.

My question: is there anyway to start that intent without *showing the barcode scanning application ? 
Example, I click on a button to scan in my app and it automatically retrieves the data (given the user is pointing the camera in an acceptable position to scan the barcode in the barcode application).

Developing an android app via DELPHI XE5

Thanks.

I'm guessing I have to look at the Flags that I can set, but I do not know which one, or even if that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this would be if the application exposed a `Service` to which you could send such an intent. In any case, handling of the intent is completely at the discretion of the target app. Whether it displays something or not is not up to you. All you get to do is send an intent that tells the app your *intent*. You don't get to specify exactly what it can or can not do, merely make suggestions via extras if they support them.

Comment: Well, thats a bummer. Thank you. How would I access a service? or even be able to tell if the app already had an exposed service ?

Comment: Same way you found out about the intent for the activity. It's only available if there's a public API available. I highly doubt your scanner app has a service that can read barcodes in the background though.